# VirtualBox errors out saying it needs more free disk space when space is clearly available

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, redhat-enterprise-linux

At my work environment we use VirtualBox for testing. It is set up as Windows host and RHEL 6 as client.

Now during testing sometimes the error message popping up which says:

> You need to free some disk space in order to continue

Trying to issue

```
df -k
```

Shows that there is plenty of disk space availble inside the OS. Here are the stats just after a Virtual Machine restore:

- **Host** - Windows 7 64 bit with plenty of available spece (77.6 GB free out of 232 GB).
- **Guest** - RHEL6 32 bit also with plenty of available space (12182828 1-k blocks, Used - 9475188, Available - 2088788).

The only solution seems to be to rollback to the previously taken snapshot and start all over again.

Unfortunately Google didn’t help at all.

Is there an easy way to work around it or better yet eliminate the error at all?

Comment: Is there plenty of disk space on the host machine?

Comment: Yup. Restore to the saved snapshot fixes the issue. I am running 2 instances on 1 host drive and have 75G available disk space out of 232G.

Comment: Are you using dynamically expanding disks for the VM?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is this a culprit?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, do you have any comments/suggestions? I do use dynamically expanding disk